# How should I protect default values, by id or add another attribute to the tables?

Tags: java, database

In my java application one region, one team, and 8 user roles are required as defaults. They can be renamed (and should be renamed by the sys admin) or disabled, but shouldn't be deleted. I want to protect them from deletion. Should I used their uuid id value from the database or should I add another attribute such as `isDefault`, true or false to those default regions, teams, users? What is the best practice?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are these UUIDs being generated in the database or application level? In my opinion, you should keep not have *hard-coded* UUIDs and use a `isDefault` field instead. What if tomorrow your requirements change and for whatever reason you need to change the way that IDs are generated? Do you want to update, package, **deploy and restart** the *N* client installations that you have? Or do you simplye prefer to write a SQL/JavaScript query that updates the existings records and that you can execute in a few moments in the several installations that you have, without any *down-time* to your client? I would prefer the second option :)

Best regards and a happy new year,
João

Comment: The uuids for the default region, teams, 8 default user roles are currently put in statically / manually on build so they are always the same. New teams, regions, user accounts with created from the application have their uuids generated at the database level.